# Why some python doesn't work on python reader or IDLE while they work on command prompt?

Tags: python, win32com

I'm trying to do an auto logger. To do that, I use these commands :

```
import win32com.client
wsh= comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
wsh.SendKeys("usernamehere")
```

I absolutely don't understand why it work perfectly on command prompt but doesn't on IDLE or python reader, it simply output : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'"

I had the same trouble with termcolor and colorama.

I'm on w10 with python 3.10.0.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: because your idle/python reader (what's that?) is in a different environment from your command prompt

Comment: python reader is the built in app that launch by double clicking on a py file, it read and execute the py file. This avoids having to use a command prompt. @2e0byo

Comment: ah right.  the principle still stands: something is running in a different env.  as a very basic starting point, have a look at sys.path and compare.  check as well that the same python version is running (it's quite easy to end up with multiple on windows), etc.  but this is basically a problem in your env, and can't really be debugged over the internet.  You might have more luck in a forum, particularly one devoted to e.g. pytonreader

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled python. I actually had 2 python (3.10 and 3.9), and now, after reinstalling various components, all my scripts works perfectly on command prompt AND python reader.
thank you so much @2e0byo !